# Error en return 0 C++

Tags: c++, funciones

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a arreglarlo?

Me sale error al ejecutarlo, uso **Dev C++**, la imagen de arriba contiene el problema de que trata el código, lo que pediría es si pueden mirar el código que tengo y encontrarle alguna falla que tenga para quitar el error que me sale al ejecutarlo, eh arreglado el codigo pero ahora me sale error en `return 0`.

Este es mi código, es un menú con funciones:

```
    #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        int main () { 
        int opc;
        int numero,nombre[100];
        int a,b,c,d;
        
        do {
            system ("cls");
            cout<<"Menu"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Determina cual es el mayor y cual es el menor: "<<endl;
            cout<<"2. Determina cual es el numero par o impar: "<<endl;
            cout<<"3. Solicite el nombre de una persona: "<<endl;
            cout<<"4. Salir "<<endl;
            cin>>opc;   
        
    switch (opc) { 
        case 1:
            cout<<"Ingrese tres valores: "<<endl;
            cin>>a;
            cin>>b;
            cin>>c;
        
            if (b > a, b > c) {
            cout<< "el numero mayor es:" << b << endl << endl;
            }
            else if (c < a, c < b){
            cout<< "el numero menor es:" << c << endl << endl;
            system ("pause");
            break;
            }
            case 2: 
            cout<<"Ingrese un valor: "<<endl;
            cin>>d;
        
            if (numero % 2 == 0) { 
            cout<<"El numero par es: "<<endl;
            }
            else { 
            cout<<"El numero impar es: "<<endl;
            }
            system ("pause");
            break;
            case 3:
            cout<<"Saludos "<<endl;
        
            for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "<<endl;
            cin>>nombre[i];
            }
            for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
            cout<<"Que pase buen dia"<<endl;
                }
            break;
            default: 
            cout<<"Opcion no valida, intente de nuevo "<<endl;
            system("pause");
    }   while (opc!=4);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: añadir caracteres basura no ayuda; las restricciones y guías para preguntar están ahí para que crees preguntas que se puedan responder de forma oportuna y adecuada. Por qué dices que no se ejecuta bien? Qué debería hacer y qué hace? con qué datos lo has probado? Eso lo podrías añadir en vez de todos los puntos que pones para saltarte la validación. Como recomendación, los enunciados también se pueden copiar y pegar como texto para facilitar que todos los usuarios puedan leerlo fácilmente.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Te falta `i++` en el for y es con `;` el separador.

Comment: Creo que vas a fallar el ejercicio, las instrucciones te piden un programa en C

Comment: si me di cuenta que habia puesto la foto equivocada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aun no se que es lo que se quiere lograr bien bien el codigo, pero tenias un poquitos de errores en el:
(b > a && b > c) se le agregan operadores logicos
(int i=0;i<100;i++) Se agrega el incremento "i++" que se hará en cada repeticion
while (opc!=4) Lo tenias dentro del "do" cerrando la llave del switch lo tenias ahí, cuando deberia ir en la ultima llave del "do"

```
do{
  switch(){
  }
}while();


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int opc;
    int numero, nombre[100];
    int a, b, c, d;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Menu" << endl;
        cout << "1. Determina cual es el mayor y cual es el menor: " << endl;
        cout << "2. Determina cual es el numero par o impar: " << endl;
        cout << "3. Solicite el nombre de una persona: " << endl;
        cout << "4. Salir " << endl;
        cin >> opc;

        switch (opc)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Ingrese tres valores: " << endl;
            cin >> a;
            cin >> b;
            cin >> c;

            if (b > a && b > c)
            {
                cout << "el numero mayor es:" << b << endl;
            }
            else if (c < a && c < b)
            {
                cout << "el numero menor es:" << c << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            cout << "Ingrese un valor: " << endl;
            cin >> d;

            if (numero % 2 == 0)
            {
                cout << "El numero par es: " << d << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "El numero impar es: " << d << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Saludos " << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                cout << "Ingrese su nombre: " << endl;
                cin >> nombre[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                cout << "Que pase buen dia " << nombre << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Opcion no valida, intente de nuevo " << endl;
        }

    } while (opc != 4);
}
```

Comment: Funciona sin el `return`?

Comment: si me funciono!

Comment: @Bicho El `return` de `main()` es el valor que el programa le retorna al sistema operativo, es opcional. Hay que compiladores que te permiten definir el `main()` como tipo `void`, y no pasa nada.

Comment: Si, si logra funcionar sin el return, aunque por buena practica siempre hay que ponerselo, a menos de que sea tipo void

Comment: Así es, un software de calidad empieza por esos detalles @LuisMontoya.

Answer (score 0):

amigo disculpa  el problema también radica en que el codigo lo tienes que colocar dentro de la función principal int main
`int main(){ //todo el código anterior return 0;}`